# How to draw a bivariate normal with a sweeping angle

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphs

I am doing a presentation in beamer.  The Cauchy distribution is the ratio of two normals and can, informally and not rigorously, be thought of as the density along a line through (0,0) as that line rotates through the bivariate normal.  I can find content to draw a bivariate normal, but I want to make clear that it is the density along that rotating angle.  Please, any code and/or suggestions would be wonderful and very appreciated!

I use MikTex through TexStudio, by the way.

I don't have any code yet.  I have found snippets of code for the bivariate normal, but drawing anything is way out of my skill set.

Comment: Welcome! You are likely to get a better response if you show us what you have so far and if you explain what you are trying to do. Remember that most people reading your question are not specialists in your discipline. However, your question seems to have nothing to do with Beamer and not to be about a graph in the `tikz-graphdrawing` sense. Sounds like a plot, if anything. If so, take a look at `pgfplots`.

Comment: As cfr said, it's always better to add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), even if it's not complete, to give us a starting point. Moreover, to show us what you want, you can even draw it by hand, take a photo with your smartphone and add the image to your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A colorful proposition.

### The output

[image]

### The code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pgfplotsset
{
  /pgfplots/colormap={spring}{rgb255=(255,0,255) rgb255=(255,255,0)}
}
\begin{document}
\def\a{3.9}
\def\slope{.88}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth']
  \begin{axis}
    [
      width=10cm,
      unit vector ratio=1 1,
      xmin = -\a,
      xmax =  \a,
      ymin = -\a,
      ymax =  \a,
      xtick distance=1,
      ytick distance=1,
      axis lines=center,
      view={0}{90},
      colormap name=spring,
    ]
    \addplot3[surf,shader=interp,patch type=bilinear,] {-exp(-.5*(x^2 + y^2)} ;
    \addplot [blue, semithick]{\slope*x} 
    node 
    [
      circle,
      fill=black, 
      inner sep=.8pt, 
      pos=.46,
      pin={[pin distance=.8cm,]320:$M(\omega) \hookrightarrow \mathcal{N}(0, I_2)$},
    ] {}
    ;
    \draw [semithick,->] (axis cs:1,0) -- + (axis direction cs:0,\slope) node [midway, label={[label distance=0pt, inner sep=0pt]right:$R(\omega) \hookrightarrow \mathcal{C}(0{,}1)$}] {};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Cheers,

Comment: Wonderful, thanks.  Someday I have to learn this part of LaTeX